# php curl on submit login (codeigniter) CSFR

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, authentication, token

Where is the problem, I don't understand.

Login with codeigniter framework

Get message "An Error Was Encountered The action you have requested is not allowed."

I think the problem there codeigniter CSFR ? How do I connect ?

Please,

```
private $url = 'http://domain';
private $username = 'username';
private $password = 'password';

public function __construct()
{

    # LOG #
    self::console('TOKEN:'.self::getToken().' COOKIE:'.self::getCookie() );

    # CURL #
    self:: curl( 
        '/admin/ajax/login', 
        array(
            'token' =>  self::getToken(),
            'username' => $this->username,
            'password' => $this->password
        ) 
    );

}

private function curl( $url, $fields = null )
{   

    $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url . $url );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, !empty($fields) ? http_build_query($fields) : null );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'\cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'\cookie.txt');
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if(curl_errno($ch))
        {
            return 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        }else{
            return print_r($result);
        }

    curl_close($ch);
}

private function getCookie()
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url.'/admin/ajax/login' );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $value);
    parse_str($value[1], $cookies);
    return $cookies['bopsystoken'];
}

private function getToken()
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url.'/login' );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch))
    {
        return 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }else{
        preg_match('/type="hidden" name="token" value="(.*?)" /mi', str_replace(array("\n","\r","\t"),'',$result), $token);
        return $token[1];
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}

private function console($e)
{
    echo '<script>console.log("'.$e.'")</script>';
}
```

Comment: CSRF is Cross-Site-Request-Forgery. This error is from the server you are requesting. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: **Error** Call to non-static method.

Comment: inside get_token function use preg_mathc($this->security->get_csrf_hash()) for taking the value of generated token.